# Jquery ajax error when upgrading to v1.5

Tags: jquery, ajax

I upgrading from v1.4.4 to v1.5. I think I have found the problem below

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Get token on page load.
    update_csrf_token();
```

The function looks like this... **EDITED**

```
function update_csrf_token()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('includes/csrf_token/'); ?>",
        dataType: "json",
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: "callbackName",
        success: function(data) {
            csrf_token = data.csrf_token;
            return data.csrf_token;
        }
    });  
}
```

I looked in firebug for the ajax request and it seems to add **?_=1297353567948** to the end of the url which makes the csrf token not generate.
How do i get rid of this or is it new to 1.5 and nothing I can do?
Thanks

Comment: I never understand returning a value from a success function.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery 1.5 will automatically add a random callback parameter, but you can override it by setting the `jsonp` and `jsonpCallback` jQuery ajax settings.

From [jQuery Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> As of jQuery 1.5, setting the jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the
>   "?callback" string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation. In this case,
>   you should also explicitly set the jsonpCallback setting. For example,
>   `{ jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }`.

The underscore parameter (`?_=...`) is a parameter containing a changing timestamp thus making the request URL to always appear something that the browser has never seen before and forcing an actual HTTP request. The parameter can be removed by enabling caching by adding `cache: true` setting to the `.ajax()` call (or by global settings: `jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache:true});`. The setting defaults to `true` with dataTypes `script` and `jsonp`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read the page and edited like my post above. But know luck, the callback string is smaller and looks like ?_=1297353567948. Any ideas?

Comment: Edited answer should fix remaining issues. Caching has existed already before jQuery 1.5, so I don't know why that problem didn't present itself until now.

Answer (score 2):

Please verify your codes and plugins (for example, the old validation plugin, that uses $.ajaxSettings as default options.
Remove codes that looks like this:

```
var settings = $.extend( {}, $.ajaxSettings, settings );
```

If you can't or don't want to do that, try add:

```
{ jsonp: null, jsonpCallback: null }
```

to your settings. So that your code should be:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('includes/csrf_token/'); ?>",
        dataType: "json",
        jsonp: null,
        jsonpCallback: null,
        success: function(data) {
            csrf_token = data.csrf_token;
            return data.csrf_token;
        }
    });
```

Or you can use $ajaxSetup() to set default settings to prevent jsonp callback:

```
$ajaxSetup({ jsonp: null, jsonpCallback: null });
```

For detail information, please refer to [Ticket #8084](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8084#comment:16).

Note: Documents of the validation plugin in the official jQuery plugin center - http: //plugins.jquery.com/project/validate is outdated (that really bugs me). It covers only version 1.5.5 of the validation plugin. Make sure referring to the home page: [jQuery plugin: Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for latest release.

Answer (score 1):

Set `cache:false` within your AJAX (don't forget the comma) and that parameter will stop getting appended. If it was jsonp related, you would see something added like:

> callback=jQuery171003826577159490807_1332979269727

But the ?_=*looks like a timestamp* is a sign that jQuery is trying to prevent any client-side caching of your request.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems and, after too much googling, I ended up it was because of the jquery.validate.min.js, that forced jsonp calls.

No more problems with the new version of JQuery Validation 1.8

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/