# How to stop jQuery from issuing second GET parameter in jsonp request?

Tags: jquery, jsonp

My code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.someDomain.com/getData.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Got an error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

It's issuing the following url to the server:

```
http://www.someDomain.com/getData.php?callback=jQuery17101679471987299621_1327694948974&_=1327694849413
```

The `callback` parameter is fine, but the `_` parameter is causing the server some problems. Is there a way I can make jQuery omit this parameter?

Comment: are you sure that this causes the error and not your .php ?

Comment: The `_=` is there to force older browsers (guess which) to not cache.

Comment: Yes, it is the .php file that is the difficulty, but that file belongs to a third party, and I have no access to the server. The .php is taking the callback name as `jQuery17101679471987299621_1327694948974&_=1327694849413`, which causes obvious difficulty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959118/jquery-ajax-error-when-upgrading-to-v1-5

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: Thanks for the link. The `cache: true,` solved it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder, please put this in an answer and I'll accept it.